# Calculate correct rate via postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here'e the table `result`'s data:

```
question_id is_correct count
64          TRUE        11
66          FALSE       20
77          FALSE       15
77          TRUE        9
```

I need to calculate the correct rate, which equals `(TRUE_COUNT)/(TRUE_COUNT+FALSE_COUNT)`. The problem for now is that some questions miss TRUE or FALSE data, I want to fill it with zero in order to do the `self join` operation and do the calculation. Is there any way to fulfill the requirement or fill with zero? Great thanks!

Expected result:

```
question_id correct_rate
64          1
66          0
77          0.625
```

Comment: How does adding rows with zero values for count affect your calculation?  I think your question needs ore detail.

Comment: Added, plz give it a look on how could I solve it in `postgresql`? Thanks! @GordonLinoff

Comment: is there a guarantee that `(TRUE_COUNT+FALSE_COUNT) <> 0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for a self-join, you can do conditional aggregation:

```
select
   question_id,
   -- to return a percentage
   100.0 * 
   max(case when is_correct = TRUE then count else 0 end) /
   sum(count)

   -- otherwise needs to add a cast if "count" is an INT
   -- max(case when is_correct = TRUE then count else 0 end) /
   -- cast(sum(count) as decimal(5,4))

from tab
group by question_id
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that it will return an integer result, so something like `4 / 10` would equal `0` instead of `0.4`

Comment: @Nicarus: Yep, so needs to add a cast.

Answer (score 2):

Conditional aggregation is correct but there are a couple of nuances:

```
SELECT
  question_id
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN is_correct THEN count ELSE 0 END)
    /(CASE WHEN SUM(count) < 1 THEN 1 ELSE SUM(count) END)::NUMERIC
FROM
  result
GROUP BY
  question_id
```

Make sure you don't end up in a divide by 0 (in case of 0/0), and ensure you cast to a decimal or numeric to get your desired rate.

Also note your desired result of .625 is not correct for 77 that would be .375 9 true / 24 total

Answer (score 1):

You should not need a `JOIN` at all. Check out below on how to conditionally aggregate your data:

```
SELECT
    question_id,
    COALESCE(SUM(count) FILTER(WHERE is_correct),0) / SUM(count)::NUMERIC AS rate
FROM
    result
GROUP BY
    question_id;

-- Older version of PostgreSQL without FILTER:

SELECT
    question_id,
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN is_correct THEN count END),0) / SUM(count)::NUMERIC AS rate
FROM
    result
GROUP BY
    question_id;
```